# Multiline User Input in Python 3 with EOD

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm stuck trying to create a new input function that accepts multiple lines of text. What I've got so far works but not for the testing program my university uses.

How do I have the terminal read the EOD signal (Ctrl + D on my Mac) rather than having a newline terminate the code?

```
buffer = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == "":
        break
    buffer.append(line)
return " ".join(buffer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this, and not have to use `input()`, but if you'd like to use `input()` it will throw an exception on `EOF` called `EOFError` which you can catch:

```
import sys

def get_lined_input():
    buffer = []
    for line in sys.stdin:
        buffer.append(line)
    return ' '.join(buffer)
```

Comment: I'll accept the answer once it lets me, but that's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: Just a note: You can also use a list comprehension to do the same thing in one line: `return ' '.join(line for lin in sys.stdin)`.